# Basic HTTP Authentication not working in Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm building a backend system for my mobile app. I want to protect the content with a basic HTTP Auth.

I have written the following code and it runs like a breeze on localhost.

```
if ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] != 'admin@denda.in' && $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] != '11test11') {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Denda Backend"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo "Wrong credentials :-(";
    exit;
}
```

But this does not work when I upload the app to GAE. I keep getting the same dialog box. Could not find any reliable help online as well.

thanks,
Krish

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question but it's nice to know it

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'])) {
    $nobasic = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'],6);            // removing 'Basic ' from the string
    $decoded = base64_decode($nobasic);                                   // decoding string with user:password
    list($client_user, $client_pass) = explode(':',$decoded);
    if ($client_user == "user" && $client_pass == "password") {
        // Successfully authenticated
    } else {
        // Authentication failed, username or password are wrong
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="site"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        echo "Wrong credentials :-(";
        exit;
    }
} else {
    // Not authenticated as there is no appropriate header in HTTP request
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="site"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo "Wrong credentials :-(";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: in 2020 I'm finding that app engine doesn't seem to pass along the proper headers :/

Comment: In 2023, am facing the same issue that CURLOPT_USERPWD is not being sent.